# C# data reporting from MS Access database / OR database type changing?

Tags: ms-access, report

I have a question about desktop database driven application that need reports output.
   Using C# 2015 and MDB database, what is best/easiest way to get data from DatagridView/Forms to reports, with parameters? Possibly without fancy/paid software packages like Crystal, DevExpress etc.
   I prefer MDB database files for my projects, because of portability an because I already have some experience with MS Access. Don't like and idea that need to install server of some kind to use other database types, because of deficiency of knowledge in that matter.
   I really like single file database that support multiple users, but if You think there is a better/easier option to change database type, please advise and explain.
Many thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. As you might already have suspected, this site has its own rules, one of them being that questions which are asking for recommendations ("what is the best library to do XY") are not completely appropriate here, as well as questions which will attract answers which are primarily opinion-based. Unfortunately, your question belongs to that category ("... what is the best/easiest way to ..."). So be prepared that somebody (not me) eventually will vote to close this question.

Comment: Design reports in Access like normal, then use MS Office Automation (requires COM) to generate and/or print reports.  I make no claims about being "best/easiest" (in fact this approach is probably rather clunky now-a-days), only that this approach requires no third-party tools and allows you to used Access Reports.

Comment: I am not against third-party tools. Just would like to get reports from C# without some extra large/expensive software package.
Can I pass arguments from form to Access reports?

Comment: The answer is perhaps "yes", since there is enough flexibility within Access Automation objects and within Access to facilitate custom behavior, but it is also not as simple as "pass[ing] arguments". Technically I think Access Reports can be started with one custom string value, but you couldn't pass an entire data recordset from C# without some clever and extensive programming in C# and VBA, for example. This is why these type of open-ended requests for alternative solutions are not good for StackOverflow--too many details required to answer properly.